# Vba code if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner in using vba code and I need a statement function to make it move to a new columns with a new starting cell output when the row offset of the first columns=1048567 to continue the processing the vba code

```
If sq(lUser_1, 2) & "" <> sqq(lUser_2) Then

    'we found a new combination, output to screen
    Range(sStartingCellOutput).Offset(lRowOffset).Resize(, 3).Value = Array(sq(lUser_1, 2), sqq(lUser_2), rTopic.Value)

    'increment the counter
    lRowOffset = lRowOffset + 1

End If
```

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce another variable to take care of the column offset.

```
dim lColOffset as long
lColOffset = 0
If sq(lUser_1, 2) & "" <> sqq(lUser_2) Then

    'we found a new combination, output to screen
    Range(sStartingCellOutput).Offset(lRowOffset, lColOffset).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
      Array(sq(lUser_1, 2), sqq(lUser_2), rTopic.Value)

    'increment the counter
    lRowOffset = lRowOffset + 1
    if lRowOffset >= Rows.Count then
        lRowOffset = 0
        lColOffset = lColOffset + 4
    end if

End If
```

I've staggered the column offset by 4. You are putting three values into the rows so this will leave a blank column. Adjust that stagger is you wish.

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: correct answer to an unclear question: +1 @FifoHsn - please accept the answer to close the question